# Отступ для формы на равне с placeholder

Tags: html, css

[image: Форма]

Как сделать отступы для текста, чтобы они были на одном уровне с placeholder ?
Когда вводишь текст

[image: Форма 2]

Comment: А как вы сделали отступ для `placeholder`? Они по дефолту должны быть на 1 уровне. Наверно, вы ставили отступ через `псевдокласс placeholder`?

Comment: `input { padding: 15px 30px; }` ...

Comment: Да, делал отступы с помощью псевдокласса placeholder

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="placeholder">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

Отступы для `placeholder` и текста, который Вы вводите в поле, одинаковы. Просто задайте `padding` для поля и эти отступы будут действовать и для `placeholder` и для текста.